# Disable rule for certain directory(ies)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm using this rule:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.(php|html|htm)($|\?)) {  
    return 302 /$1?$args;  
}
```

to remove the .php/.html/.htm extension for the URL, and now I'd like this disable this rule for a dir like: `/site/ajax`.

This is my full server config:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.net;
    listen 443;
    root   /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/privkey.pem;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /site/ajax/ {
        index index.php;
        break;
    }

    #Remove .php | .html | .htm
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.(php|html|htm)($|\?)) {  
        return 302 /$1?$args;  
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
    }

    location /site/query {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$args;
        index manage.php; #Change index for query folder
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 403 /403.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
}
```

is it this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a negative lookahead assertion in the regular expression. For example:

```
^/(?!site/ajax)([^?]*)\.(php|html|htm)($|\?))
```